# Textures are appearing purple

Tags: texturing

I rendered a scene and all of the textures worked perfectly. I saved, left, and move some textures to different files. now, when I came back and I rendered, part of the texture was missing. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Use this menu option:
File -> External Data -> Find Missing Files

(*Then, obviously, select the folder that you're likely to find the missing textures. If they still don't appear, then go a directory level higher and try again. Rinse and repeat until Blender finds them.*)

[image]

Once the textures are loaded in, I'd reccomend doing two things:

1. Click "Make all Paths Relative"
2. Tick the "Automatically Pack into .blend" option